# AWS Sagemaker notebook , load files and get mel spectrogram is too slow on ml.t3.xlarge

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, audio, amazon-sagemaker, librosa

Hello the notebook runs on an ml.t3.xlarge instance so i dont think its a memory issue. I tried accessing aws technical support but i cant use it without being Premium member ( i run sagemaker on free mode)

So i have created a terminal in sagemaker notebook and then downloaded some audio data ( from dcase2021)
which i then want to iterate and load each file and extract mel spectrogram from it then stack them all into a numpy array.

```
def preprocess_audio(filename):
    # Load the audio file
    audio, sr = librosa.load(filename)

    # Reshape the audio to have three channels
    if audio.ndim == 1:
        audio = np.stack([audio]*3, axis=-1)
    elif audio.shape[1] == 2:
        audio = np.concatenate([audio, np.zeros_like(audio)], axis=-1)

    # Compute the spectrogram with 128 mel bands, a window size of 1024 samples and a 
    #hop length of 512 samples
    spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=audio, sr=sr, n_mels=128, 
      n_fft=1024, hop_length=512, fmin=0, fmax=None)
    mel_spectrogram = librosa.power_to_db(spectrogram)

    # Resize the spectrogram to (224, 224)
    resized_spectrogram = resize(mel_spectrogram, (224, 224), anti_aliasing=True)

    # Normalize the spectrogram
    normalized_spectrogram = (resized_spectrogram - np.min(resized_spectrogram)) / 
    (np.max(resized_spectrogram) - np.min(resized_spectrogram))

    # Stack the spectrogram to create three channels
    processed_audio = np.stack([normalized_spectrogram] * 3, axis=-1)

    return processed_audio
```

The problem is that this on my pc or google colab runs fast, i have tried different notebooks (conda_tensorflow2_p310) and conda_python3 but both have the same lag

Before i try another machine learning cloud platform or upgrade aws sagemaker to paid service , could this be a problem in aws sagemaker or something ?

Comment: You are not specifying sr= in the librosa.load call - this may trigger resampling, which is quite slow.

Comment: You should check the IO and CPU performance of your different platforms.